# Como Generar un jar en java siendo un proyecto Maven en netbeans 18

Tags: java

Saludos tengo mi proyecto Java en Netbeans 18 cuando agrego la dependencia Mysql 8.1.0 y ejecuto todo ok. Sin embargo cuando realizo el Build y me dirijo a la carpeta target me arroja el error [image: Cabe destacar que eh probado agregando Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")]

Answer (score 0):

Quizás te hayas olvidado un elemento importante en tu archivo pom.xml el cual es el plugin de maven para hacer el archivo JAR con dependencias, el cual lo debes copiar antes de la etiqueta dependencies

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                <manifest>
                    <mainClass>
                        com.invmiranda.SistemaLista.main
                    </mainClass>
                </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Dentro de la etiqueta mainClass deberías cambiar el nombre "main" por el archivo principal de tu proyecto. Yo lo puse de tal manera debido a la consola de tu captura.

Puedes leer más formas de crear un archivo ejecuta con maven en el siguiente artículo de Baeldung: https://www.baeldung.com/executable-jar-with-maven